# check property of complex class with generic list using reflection

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, compare

hi i've a complex class with generic list and i need to check difference from two classes

this is is my class

```
public partial class Contatto
{

    [DataMember]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    private int? tyContatto { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DContatto DContatto { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RagioneSociale { get; set; }

    private int? tySesso{get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public DSesso DSesso { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TsValidita { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DtNascita { get; set; }

    private int? idComune { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Comune Comune { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CdFiscale { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PartitaIva { get; set; }

    private int? tyIso { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DIso DIso { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? IdUser { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Telefono> LsTelefono { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Mail> LsMail { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Indirizzo> LsIndirizzo { get; set; }

}
```

and this is my recursively method

```
    private static object CheckRecursivelyDifference(object old, object nuevo)
    {
        var oType = old.GetType();
        foreach (var oProperty in oType.GetProperties())
        {
            var oOldValue = oProperty.GetValue(old, null); //letto dal SqlServer
            var oNewValue = oProperty.GetValue(nuevo, null);  //letto dal gestionale

            if (oProperty.PropertyType.Module.ScopeName != "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary")
                CheckRecursivelyDifference(oOldValue, oNewValue);
            else
            {
                // this will handle the scenario where either value is null
                if (!object.Equals(oOldValue, oNewValue))
                {
                    if (oNewValue == null && oOldValue != null) //vince sempre il vecchio gestionale
                        oProperty.SetValue(nuevo, oOldValue);
                }
            }

        }
        return nuevo;
    }
```

the method work for a normal class but when read a property as System.Collection.Generic.List<> not work

my question is how i can check System.Collection.Generic.List<>  and inheritance property.

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do when it comes to objects that are lists is to check if they are indeed lists,

```
public static bool IsGenericList(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return false;

            try
            {
                var val =  value as IList;
                if (val == null)
                    return false;

                if ((typeof(BaseConversion)).IsAssignableFrom(val.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

also exclude indexed parameters like this["test"],etc

```
objType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0
```

on your

> var oProperty in oType.GetProperties()

line.